# Location-based Augmented Reality Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, location, augmented-reality

I am looking for an Android SDK for a location-based AR app I am developing.

These are the features I am looking for:

1. Open-source framework preferred (Wikitude API requires an external install which is inconvenient).
2. My application should easily open/close the camera view. Specifically, I'd like to open the camera view when the user holds the phone straight up and switch to a map view when it is flat. It would be great if the SDK already supports this :)
3. I can add POIs from my application (not loading from a remote POI service) to the camera view, then the SDK would display markers within some distance from my current location.

I hope my description is clear enough. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: As a followup, after trying so many different forks of Mixare, http://code.google.com/p/android-augment-reality-framework/ is the easiest and most simplistic to extend on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the AR part you can use this [source code](http://www.mixare.org/). For the 2nd functionality use the sensor to launch the intents. And the 3rd use a MapActivity, you can start with this [example](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)
Good luck!

Comment: Looks interesting .. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try metaio [Mobile SDK](http://www.metaio.com/software/mobile-sdk/) that offers complete location based AR. The popular AR browser [junaio](http://www.junaio.com) is based on this SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use junaio. Its free and supports both android and iphone platforms
see the following link
http://www.junaio.com/

Coding also very easy with junaio. Its PHP

Comment: I understand junaio is not free. You can use junaio ar browser but it has watermark which you cant remove unless you purchase license. As far as I know the best solution so far is mixare ar.